# How do I remove an Armor Stands's legs?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm making a floating armor stand, and I don't want it to have legs. I'm putting a helmet and chestplate on it, and I would like the arms to be visible.

How can I remove just the legs?

Comment: Are you putting anything on the armour stand? If so, you can set the armour stand to be invisible, then just not put pants on it.

Comment: I'm putting a helmet and chestplate on it. And the arms need to be visible.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot completely *remove* the wooden legs of an ArmorStand in vanilla Minecraft whilst still keeping the arms visible. You could, however, position them so that they cannot be seen.

To hide the baseplate (the stone part), set the `NoBasePlate` tag to `1b`.

Use the `Pose` tag compound to position the ArmorStand's parts. I'd recommend using something like [this tool](http://haselkern.github.io/Minecraft-ArmorStand/) as this is a pain to do manually.

With this, you can have its legs folded up into its chestplate, like this:

```
/summon ArmorStand ~ ~ ~ {NoBasePlate:1b,ShowArms:1b,Pose:{LeftLeg:[180f,0f,0f],RightLeg:[180f,0f,0f]}}
```

Final result, with armor:

[image]